# Single word for an idiom giving advice

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, idioms

I'm trying to find a word referring to an idiom that gives advice (e.g. "Fake it till you make it"). "Nugget of wisdom" is kind of what I'm looking for, but I want a single word, not another idiom.

Edit: I should specify that I'm looking for a word that describes "Fake it till you make it".

Comment: Certainly "parable" fits a brief story illustrating some lesson, but I'm not thinking of anything for just a phrase that instructs.

Comment: Playing crosswords? :-)

Comment: Nope. Writing an English essay. I should clarify that I'm looking for something to describe "Fake it till you make it"

Comment: Maybe *Yodaisms*?

Comment: The answer is "proverb" - it's astounding nobody has pointed this out.

Comment: "Fake it till you make it" is a "modern, contemporary proverb"

Comment: For "fake it till you make it" I would use the word **motto** or **slogan**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pithy statements that give advice, e.g. "Fake it till you make it" (not a particularly good one, however...) are called [aphorisms](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aphorism):

> A tersely phrased statement of a truth or opinion; an adage.

They are also known as adages, maxims, axioms, etc.

Common aphorisms are easy to recognize, and they aren't necessarily idioms:

> - Actions speak louder than words.
> - To err is human, to forgive divine.
> - Necessity is the mother of invention.
> - Don't put all your eggs in the same basket.
> - People in glass houses shouldn't throw stones.

The last two are idioms. However, *Fake it 'til you make it* is not.

Comment: An aphorism is "a pithy observation which contains a general truth."  the OP is asking "what is an aphorism which gives advice".  This is, of course, a **proverb**.

Answer (score 5):

There seem to be lots of words in English for accepted wisdom expressed pithily in the form of a particular situation: adage, proverb, aphorism, saw, saying, etc. Of these, 'adage' seems to express most prominently the advisory part which the questioner wants. The OED defn is: "A traditional maxim; a proverb or short statement expressing a general truth". I use 'adage' when I agree with the wisdom expressed, and 'aphorism' or 'proverb' or 'saw' or 'saying' when I am neutral about the truth of the wisdom expressed.

Comment: The answer (when it **gives advice**) is a proverb.  An adage is more an ingenious, wise **observation** (like "out of sight, out of mind").  The example given is of course a proverb.

Answer (score 2):

- adage
- truism
- saying
- mantra
- maxim
- kernel
- nugget
- old chestnut

Answer (score 1):

When the advice comes in the form of overused (and, not particularly pertinent adages,) they (the adages) are called ***platitudes***.

Answer (score 0):

'Punt' denotes a plan, albeit an iffy one.
It's used as a verb.

To 'google' = to research.
To 'punt' = to 'go with that plan'.